# Incorrect syntax near AND clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this JOIN:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         VOUCHER, TAXITEMGROUP, TAXCODE, TAXAMOUNT, TAXAMOUNTCUR, SOURCERECID, GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY 
     FROM 
         ##TGJAE TT
     WHERE 
         (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%')) TTRISR 
AND TT.POSTINGTYPE IN (14, 236, 71) 
AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA  
AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 
AND ON C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTRISR.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_SOURCERECID = TTRISR.SOURCERECID 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTRISR.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND TTRISR.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = PRO.TTGJAEF_GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

But when I execute with SQL Server Management Studio, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'

I don't find problems with my `AND` clause, can anyone explain me what is wrong with my join? Regards

Comment: (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%')) TTRISR <--- this line produces error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly formatted code is always easier to read and debug.

You have your `WHERE` and `ON` clauses all over the place.

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
            (
                  SELECT VOUCHER
                        ,TAXITEMGROUP
                        ,TAXCODE
                        ,TAXAMOUNT
                        ,TAXAMOUNTCUR
                        ,SOURCERECID
                        ,GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY 
                    FROM ##TGJAE TT
                    WHERE TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%'
                      AND TT.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71) 
                      AND TT.TRANSDATE between @FECHA_INI AND @FECHA  
                      AND TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 
            ) TTRISR 
 ON C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTRISR.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_SOURCERECID = TTRISR.SOURCERECID 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTRISR.TAXITEMGROUP 
AND TTRISR.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = PRO.TTGJAEF_GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `AND ON` at the end of line 6/begin of line 7. You probably want to delete that `AND`.